# Derived classes' properties not getting value

Tags: json, flutter, dart, inheritance, deserialization

Say one has an `abstract` `Car` class with a derived `Cabrio` class.

From a REST api he recieves a JSON with data

```
abstract class Car {
  int id;
  String name;
  String description;

  Car({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.description,
  });

  factory Car.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json, String type) {
    Car car;
    if (type == 'cabrio') car = Cabrio.fromJson(json);
    // other possible if-statements
    car.id = int.parse(json['id']);
    car.name = json['name'];
    car.description = json['description'];
    return car;
  }


class Cabrio extends Car {
  String roofMaterial;
  String someOtherProp;

  Cabrio({
    id,
    name,
    this.roofMaterial,
    this.someOtherProp
  }) : super(
            id: id,
            name: name,
            description: description);

  factory Cabrio.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
    Cabrio(
        roofMaterial: json['roof_material'],
        someOtherProp: json['some_other_prop']
    );
}

dynamic dyn = jsonDecode(response.body);
Cabrio cabrio = Car.fromJson(dyn[0], 'cabrio');
cabrio.roofMaterial // null  
cabrio.someOtherProp // null 
return cabrio;
```

Why is `cabrio.roofMaterial` or `cabrio.someOtherProp` `null` ?

**Why I am taking this approach**

I didn't like seeing for example

```
id: json['id']
```

in all derived classes. This approach is to prevent such redundancy

**What I know**

- according to the debugger, the properties of the derived class `Cabrio` are set correctly by the json values in it's `fromJson`
- when inspecting the `car` object at `car.name = json['name']` the derived class' properties (like `cabrio.roofMaterial`) are already `null`

**What I consider to be a problem**
at

```
if (type == 'cabrio') car = Cabrio.fromJson(json, type);
```

I am 'pushing' a `cabrio` object into a `Car` object (which has less properties than `Cabrio`). But that should not be wrong since it's just a parent class type

Comment: Which version of flutter are you using? Can you post a working example? You can paste your code on to dartpad.dev and try running it there. The current code does not compile with a nullable version of dart. Parameters to the constructor of Car should be `required`, Cabrio's params should be typed, and so on..

Comment: Which version of flutter are you using? - 2.8.2
<> Can you post a working example? 
- I can consider this but not immediatly
<> The current code does not compile with a nullable version of dart
- correct for I do not use that
<> Parameters to the constructor of `Car` should be required, `Cabrio's` params should be typed
- this does not affect the problem in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're needing in this example is an explicit type cast after you call `Car.fromJson(...)` to ensure that the type you're dealing with is `Cabrio` which has the extra fields rather than an instance of `Car`

`final cabrio = Car.fromJson(json, 'cabrio') as Cabrio;`

I spent some time to update your code to a newer version of Dart with the changes required to ensure that these fields were no longer null

https://gist.github.com/MarkOSullivan94/60ce6625538e16f373c5c1d6254952e9